# Customer date start time

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

When my application starts I have a datetimepicker for a start time and end time.

```
dvSubmittedDateBegin.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dvSubmittedDateBegin.CustomFormat = "MMM dd yyyy  - hh mm tt";
```

Everything works.  However I've been asked to have the start default default at 5AM.

I created a new datetime and assigned the `dvSubmittedDateBegin.Value - dt;`

However the new datetime I guess I have to specify every int?

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 6, 24, 05, 00, 0);
```

What happens tomorrow when its 6/25?  Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about like;

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
```

or more simple

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(5);
```

You will get the current date from midnight with [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you will add `5` hours to it and it will be 5 AM of the current day.

Comment: Soner, that did it with DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(5);

Comment: Aside: This works, but only by accident of a poor API.  As we know, `.Today` returns a `DateTime` with the time explicitly set to `00:00`, so this will work, but reading the code, one would think we were always moving by an elapsed time of 5 hours.  This isn't necessarily true, since some days have skipped or repeated time due to daylight saving time transitions.  In other words, even though you call `AddHours(5)`, it really may have been 4 hours or 6 hours in elapsed time to reach the 5:00 hour.

Comment: @MattJohnson You are right about that. DST is a critical issue on this case.  Even we checking `IsDaylightSavingTime` method of `TimeZoneInfo` before we add this `AddHours(5)` value, this wouldn't solve all of it since if current timezone doesn't support DST, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AddDays(), AddHours(), AddMinutes() etc. methods:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(5);
```

Comment: Well its 9AM here currently so that sets the time to 2PM.  The default time in the datetimepicker needs to always be 5AM then of course they can change that themselves if they want a different time.

Comment: I edited the code while you were commenting, sorry. It has to be DateTime.Today (which is at midnight) and not DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that would return a particular date where you pass all the components and define time components as default parameters:

```
DateTime CreateDateWith5amStart(int year, int month, int day, int hour = 5, int minute = 0, int second = 0) 
{
    return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second) 
}
```

If they provide only date components, it will set time to 5 a.m. If they need a different time, they can provide time components.

Comment: Really, no need such a method since it will be handled it's property and/or methods.